# Force maximum number of records with attribute in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

In Django, is there a "Djangonic" way to ensure a model doesn't have more than `n` records with a certain value for an attribute?

For instance, how to ensure on the example below that no more of two records for `MyModel` have `my_attribute` set to `True`?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
     my_attribute= models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write some simple validation into a custom clean or save method.

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if (self.my_attribute == True 
        and MyModel.objects.filter(my_attribute=True).count() >= 2):
        raise ValidationError('Two MyModel obj already have my_attribute=True!')
    super(MyModel, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```